# MySQL - select rows having certain values in second table

Tags: mysql, filter

Let's say i have these two tables:

people:

```
id | name
---------
1  | John 
2  | Jack
3  | Pepe
```

jobs_people_relations:

```
job | person
------------
15  | 1
16  | 1
15  | 2
16  | 3
```

And I want to select all people who have job #15 and #16, but no people who have only job #15 or only #16. It means I want to receive John. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

- You can do a `Group By` on the person details.
- Use conditional aggregation in `Having` clause to filter out the case where a person has `job = 15` **AND** `job = 16`.

Try the following:

```
SELECT
  p.id, 
  p.name 
FROM people AS p
JOIN jobs_people_relations AS jpr ON jpr.person = p.id 
GROUP BY p.id, p.name 
HAVING 
  SUM(jpr.job = 15) AND 
  SUM(jpr.job = 16)
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, you are right, there is no intersect in mysql. (Didn't expect a post saying: "here's how it works, but it's not working" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems little vague, however in T-SQL you can try this

```
Select 
Distinct name 
From people 
Inner Join jobs_people_relations 
On people.id = jobs_people_relations.person
Where people.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select p.id, p.name from people p
join jobs_people_relations r on p.id = r.person
where r.job in(15,16)
group by id, name
having count(*) = 2
```